# Python: Dynamically adding function to a class, whose name is contained in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best way to create a new member function of a class with function name contained as string? Also, this new function is merely as pass-through for another object(helper class), which has the same function name but with variable arguments. I use lambda to achieve this, but I don't know how to handle the scenario, where my pass-through wrapper would be more than one-statement (which is my requirement)

```
# This is a helper class
class Compensation:
   def bonus(self):
       return 10000
   def salary(self):
       # Do something
   def stack(self):
       # Do something

# This is a employer class
class employee:
   def __init__(self):
       self.compensation = Compensation()

# This is a wrapper that creates the function
def passThru(funcName):
    fn = "employee."+funcName+"=" + "lambda self, *arg: self.compensation." + funcName +"(*arg)"
    exec(fn)

fnNames = ["bonus", "salary", "stocks"]
for items in fnNames: passThru(items)

emp = employee()
emp.bonus() # returns 1000
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Whatever it is there is probably a better way especially because eval 
(exec) is evil.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All that trickery with `exec` gives me a headache ;-)  I'm not exactly clear on what you want to do, but adding a new method with a name given by a string is really quite easy.  For example,

```
class employee:
    pass

# Some multiline-function.
def whatever(self, a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c

e = employee()

# Make `whatever` an `employee` method with name "add".
setattr(employee, "add", whatever)
print e.add(2, 9)
```

Whenever you're reaching for `exec`, you're *probably* missing a straightforward way.

EDIT:  an oddity here is that if someone tries to display `e.add`, they'll get a string claiming its name is `whatever`.  If that bothers you, you can add, e.g.,

```
whatever.__name__ = "add"
```

### Fleshing it out

Is this closer to what you want?  Note that @gnibbler suggested much the same, although more telegraphically:

```
class Compensation:
    def bonus(self, a):
        return 10000 + a
    def salary(self):
        return 20000
    def stack(self, a=2, b=3):
        return a+b

class employee:
    def __init__(self):
        self.comp = Compensation()


e = employee()

for name in "bonus", "salary", "stack":
    def outer(name):
        def f(self, *args, **kw):
            return getattr(self.comp, name)(*args, **kw)
        f.__name__ = name
        return f
    setattr(employee, name, outer(name))

print e.bonus(9)
print e.salary()
print e.stack(b="def", a="abc")
```

That displays:

```
10009
20000
abcdef
```

All that said, you might want to re-think your architecture.  It's strained.

Comment: Thanks Tim. My requirement is to have whatever call another object's add function, so e.add(2,9) should call e.comp.add(2,9). I have 100s of such functions in my architecture which would merely call another object's function with a same name and I need to find better way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks Tim. This really helps. I will think about reworking the architecture.

Answer (score 2):

You want `setattr`. Let's say you have:

```
>>> inst = Foo(10)
>>> class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

>>> inst = Foo(10)
>>> inst2 = Foo(50)
```

If you want to add a method to all instances of the class, then `setattr` on the class. This function will end up being an unbound method on the class, becoming bound in each instance, so it will take the `self` param:

```
>>> setattr(inst.__class__, "twice_x", lambda self: self.x * 2)
>>> inst.twice_x()
20
>>> inst2.twice_x()
100
```

If you want to add the function to just one instance of the class, then `setattr` on the instance itself. This will be a regular function which will not take the implicit `self` argument:

```
>>> setattr(inst, "thrice_x", lambda: inst.x * 3)
>>> inst.thrice_x()
30
>>> inst2.thrice_x()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    inst2.thrice_x()
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'thrice_x'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `setattr`/`getattr`.

```
for func_name in fnNames:
    setattr(employee, func_name, (lambda self, *args:getattr(self.compensation, func_name)(*args)))
```

This still has a problem because you need the lambda function to be [closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) over `func_name`. While you could create a closure with another lambda, I'll pull it out into another function for readability

```
for func_name in fnNames:
    def f(func_name):  # close the lambda over "func_name"
        return lambda self, *args:getattr(self.compensation, func_name)(*args)

    setattr(employee, items, f(func_name))
```